# What test to use to check whether two groups take the same to run 5 kilometers?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, mean

I have the data for 3 groups A,B,C with the times of run of 5 kilometers.

$ \begin{matrix}
Group A & Group B & Group C \\
27.5  & 35.3  & 45.8 \\
30.6 & 40.2  & 42.6 \\
28.5 & 33.8  & 32.4 \\
36.6  & 28.2  & 37.6 \\
27.9 & 35.3  & 34.4 \\
33.8 & 31.6 \\
29.2  & 29.7 \\
35.8 
\end{matrix}  $

Now we suppose no data is available for Group C and only the data for **Groups A and B** are available. I know that the data for both Groups A and B have the **same underlying population variance**.

***I would like to test whether Groups A and B take the same time to complete 5K.
What is the name of the appropriate test to do this and why?***

**My first approach** was to choose the F-test because of the information about the variance, but as far as I read it **checks** the equality of variances so maybe that;s not the right thinking?

Also, is ignoring one group(C) makes a difference for us?

Comment: This is a textbook t-test problem.  After all, your substantive question -- do the groups take the same time -- is not addressed by comparing group or population variances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not uncommon for beginners at statistical testing
have some misconceptions. There are a few in your Question, so it seems worthwhile to give a detailed answer.

Suppose you have the two samples below and (somehow) know that
they are random samples from normal populations
with the same variance. Relying on that information, you could use a pooled
2-sample t test of $H_0: \mu_a = \mu_b$ against
the alternative $H_a: \mu_a \ne \mu_b.$

I will show that $H_0$ cannot be rejected in favor
of $H_a$ at the 5% level of significance, using R.

```
a = c(27.5, 30.6, 28.5, 36.6, 27.9, 33.8, 29.2, 35.8)
b = c(35.3, 40.2, 33.8, 28.2, 35.3, 31.6, 29.7)
t.test(a, b, var.eq=T)

          Two Sample t-test

data:  a and b
t = -1.112, df = 13, p-value = 0.2863
alternative hypothesis: 
  true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -6.489691  2.078977
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 31.23750  33.44286
```

This hardly guarantees that Teams A and B would
tie in a 5K race, but it does show that you
would be foolish to use these data to predict
that one team is likely to beat the other.
The *sample means* $\bar X_a = 31.23750, \bar X_b = 33.44286$
are 'nearly' the same. They are not enough different to
pick a favorite. (See @whuber's Comment.)

The P-value $0.2863 > 0.05 = 5\%$ shows that
we cannot reject $H_0$ at the 5% level. Notice
that the 95% confidence interval contains $0$
so that something "near" a tie might be a reasonable
guess at the outcome of a 5K race.

If you want to learn how to do a pooled t test on your own (as maybe
on an exam), then
you should look at the formulas in your textbook
and compute the results above using a calculator:

- First, check to make sure I copied your data correctly.
- Then find the 'pooled' variance estimate (perhaps
  denoted by $S_p^2$ based on the sample variances and
  sample sizes).
- Next, find the pooled $T$ statistic.
- For the final computation, use printed tables of t distributions to
  find the critical value $c$ such that you would
  reject $H_0$ only if $|T| \ge c.$
- For that, you
  need to look at the row of a printed t table
  for $\nu = n_1 + n_2 - 2 = 13$ degrees of freedom.

Computer output for a pooled 2-sample t test usually
gives a P-value (such as $0.2863$ above). I'm not sure
whether you are expected to know how P-values are computed.

*Notes:* (1) If you were *not* sure that the two population
variances are equal, you'd need to use a Welch 2-sample
t test, which does not assume equal population variances.
The Welch test requires computation of an 'adjusted
degrees of freedom' $\nu^\prime,$ based on sample sizes and sample
variances. [For the data above, $\nu^\prime = 12.279 < \nu = 13.]$

(2) If you wanted to do a formal test whether the population variances are equal, you could use a standard F test,
implemented in R as `var.test`.

```
var.test(a,b)

              F test to compare two variances

data:  a and b
F = 0.81956, num df = 7, denom df = 6, p-value = 0.7915
alternative hypothesis: 
 true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1438969 4.1949988
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
         0.8195603
```

The F test, especially for sample sizes as small as yours,
is not very reliable. Here it happens not to raise the alarm
that population variances are unequal, but it is risky to
depend on that. Good statistical practice is to do the
Welch 2-sample t test, unless you have *reliable advance
information* that population variances are very nearly equal. (This
might come from extensive prior work with data of a particular kind.)

The Welch 2-sample t test gives P-value $0.2907 > 0.05,$ so
the verdict that we can tell no difference between population running times $\mu_a$ and $\mu.b$ remains unchanged.

```
t.test(a, b)

           Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  a and b
t = -1.1042, df = 12.279, p-value = 0.2907
alternative hypothesis: 
 true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -6.546231  2.135517
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 31.23750  33.44286
```

Comment: That's an AMAZING answer, thank you so much